# Permission denied on file django app published on IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, office365, token

I Have a django app puplished in my company's IIS that is reading the mail from an specific mail inbox registered in the tenant. I succesfully registered my python app on the tenant and use the credentials generated to read the inbox folder. everything works when I run my app locally using the manager.py file. However, when I want to enter the app through the IIS and I click on the view responsible of reading the mail i get the error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'o365_token.txt'. I went to the folder where my files are and added the IIS group to have total control over the folder and still not good results.

Relevant part of the code:

```
import O365
from O365 import Account, Connection,  MSGraphProtocol, Message

credentials=(client id, client secret)

        account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id=tenant id)
        if account.authenticate():
           print('Authenticated!')
        account.connection.refresh_token()

        if('QQ_FV_Mail' in diccionario['cadenaMail']):
            mailbox = account.mailbox(resource='mail1')

        elif('EE_FV_Mail' in diccionario['cadenaMail']):
            mailbox = account.mailbox(resource='mail2)
        query = mailbox.new_query()

        inbox=mailbox.inbox_folder()
```

Also I get the following error: Exception Location:c:\python39\lib\pathlib.py in _opener, line 1109

Could it be that python does not have the right privileges to read the file?

Full traceback error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: HOST/farmacoVigilancia/Revistasmedicas/

Django Version: 2.1.15
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'farmacoVigilancia']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\first_project\farmacoVigilancia\views.py" in revistasmedicas
  1133.         if account.authenticate():

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\O365\account.py" in authenticate
  111.             return self.con.request_token(None, requested_scopes=scopes)

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py" in request_token
  531.             self.token_backend.save_token()

File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\O365\utils\token.py" in save_token
  205.         with self.token_path.open('w') as token_file:

File "c:\python39\lib\pathlib.py" in open
  1241.         return io.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline,

File "c:\python39\lib\pathlib.py" in _opener
  1109.         return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)

Exception Type: PermissionError at /farmacoVigilancia/Revistasmedicas/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'o365_token.txt'
```

Comment: There are three reasons may cause this issue, so you'd better check that. First is application pool identity has read and write permission to the folder. Please add `IIS APPPOOL\app pool name` and make it has control over to folder. Second is make sure the application is opening a specific file not folder. Third is making sure there's no other process using or refering the file when application try to open it. What's the line 1109 code is?

Comment: Hello, I already added the App with total control on the folder with no results. For the second point, I don't explicitly open the file but the O365 API does it. I also don't see any process tryign to open the token file.